# Colocar a paginação dentro do footer

Tags: php

Criei um código .php que faz consultas ao banco e retorna os resultados imprimindo-os na tela, tambem imprime uma paginação, gostaria de imprimir esta pagina dentro de uma tag footer porem sem ter de refazer as consultas por quantidade de resultados no banco, limit e sim reaproveitar da parte que imprime os resultados na tela.

Código .PHP

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Exibe produtos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="produtos">
        <p>
            Produtos com esta consulta
        </p>
        <?php
            include_once "QueryInDB.php";
            include_once "CountInDB.php";
            include_once "Consulta.class.php";

            imprime();
            function imprime(){

                //Cria uma consulta com os parametros passados pela URL
                $consulta = new Consulta();
                $consulta->resultType = $_GET['resultType'];
                $consulta->search = $_GET['search'];

                //verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página
                $pagina = (isset($_GET['p']))? $_GET['p'] : 1;

                //seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens
                $consulta->registros = 2;

                //conta o total de itens
                $total = CountInDB::search($consulta);

                //calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima
                $numPaginas = ceil($total/$consulta->registros);

                //variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual
                $consulta->inicio = ($consulta->registros*$pagina)-$consulta->registros;

                //Realiza e armazena a consulta
                $produtos = queryInDB::search($consulta);

                foreach($produtos as $produto){
                    echo $produto['id']." - ";
                    echo $produto['nome']." - ";
                    echo $produto['descricao']." - ";
                    echo "R$ ".$produto['valor']."<br />";
                }

                //Cria uma string para passagem de parametros pela URL
                $query = http_build_query($consulta);

                //Exibe a paginação
                if($pagina > 1){
                    echo "<a href='exibir.php?{$query}&p=".($pagina - 1)."' class='controle'>&laquo; anterior</a>".'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                }
                for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++){
                    $ativo = ($i == $pagina) ? 'numativo' : '';
                    echo "<a href='exibir.php?{$query}&p=".$i."' class='numero ".$ativo."'> ".$i." </a>".'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                }    
                if($pagina < $numPaginas){
                    echo "<a href='exibir.php?{$query}&p=".($pagina + 1)."' class='controle'>proximo &raquo;</a>".'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <footer id="pagincao">
        <!-- PAGINAÇÃO DEVE FICAR -->
        <p>
            Fim dos Produtos
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode parametrizar sua função, para que exiba apenas a listagem, apenas o rodapé ou os dois, assim:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Exibe produtos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="produtos">
        <p>
            Produtos com esta consulta
        </p>
        <?php
            include_once "QueryInDB.php";
            include_once "CountInDB.php";
            include_once "Consulta.class.php";

            function imprime($imprime = TRUE, $paginacao = FALSE){


                //Cria uma consulta com os parametros passados pela URL
                $consulta = new Consulta();
                $consulta->resultType = $_GET['resultType'];
                $consulta->search = $_GET['search'];

                //verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página
                $pagina = (isset($_GET['p']))? $_GET['p'] : 1;

                //seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens
                $consulta->registros = 2;

                //conta o total de itens
                $total = CountInDB::search($consulta);

                //calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima
                $numPaginas = ceil($total/$consulta->registros);

                //variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual
                $consulta->inicio = ($consulta->registros*$pagina)-$consulta->registros;

                //Realiza e armazena a consulta
                $produtos = queryInDB::search($consulta);
                if($imprime){
                    foreach($produtos as $produto){
                        echo $produto['id']." - ";
                        echo $produto['nome']." - ";
                        echo $produto['descricao']." - ";
                        echo "R$ ".$produto['valor']."<br />";
                    }
                }

                if($paginacao){
                    //Cria uma string para passagem de parametros pela URL
                    $query = http_build_query($consulta);

                    //Exibe a paginação
                    if($pagina > 1){
                        echo "<a href='exibir.php?{$query}&p=".($pagina - 1)."' class='controle'>&laquo; anterior</a>".'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    }
                    for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++){
                        $ativo = ($i == $pagina) ? 'numativo' : '';
                        echo "<a href='exibir.php?{$query}&p=".$i."' class='numero ".$ativo."'> ".$i." </a>".'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    }    
                    if($pagina < $numPaginas){
                        echo "<a href='exibir.php?{$query}&p=".($pagina + 1)."' class='controle'>proximo &raquo;</a>".'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    }
                }
            }
            imprime();

        ?>
    </div>
    <footer id="pagincao">
        <?php imprime(FALSE, TRUE); ?>
        <p>
            Fim dos Produtos
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

---

Existem maneira muito mais eficazes de fazer isso, porém depende muito da aplicação, por isso não vou sugeri-las, dada a sua aplicação acho que essa é a maneira mais rápida.

Outra forma:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Exibe produtos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="produtos">
        <p>
            Produtos com esta consulta
        </p>
        <?php
            include_once "QueryInDB.php";
            include_once "CountInDB.php";
            include_once "Consulta.class.php";

            //Cria uma consulta com os parametros passados pela URL
            $consulta = new Consulta();
            $consulta->resultType = $_GET['resultType'];
            $consulta->search = $_GET['search'];

            //verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página
            $pagina = (isset($_GET['p']))? $_GET['p'] : 1;

            //seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens
            $consulta->registros = 2;

            //conta o total de itens
            $total = CountInDB::search($consulta);

            //calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima
            $numPaginas = ceil($total/$consulta->registros);

            //variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual
            $consulta->inicio = ($consulta->registros*$pagina)-$consulta->registros;

            //Realiza e armazena a consulta
            $produtos = queryInDB::search($consulta);
            foreach($produtos as $produto){
                echo $produto['id']." - ";
                echo $produto['nome']." - ";
                echo $produto['descricao']." - ";
                echo "R$ ".$produto['valor']."<br />";
            }

            ?>
    </div>
    <footer id="pagincao">
            <?php

            //Cria uma string para passagem de parametros pela URL
            $query = http_build_query($consulta);

            //Exibe a paginação
            if($pagina > 1){
                echo "<a href='exibir.php?{$query}&p=".($pagina - 1)."' class='controle'>&laquo; anterior</a>".'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            }
            for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++){
                $ativo = ($i == $pagina) ? 'numativo' : '';
                echo "<a href='exibir.php?{$query}&p=".$i."' class='numero ".$ativo."'> ".$i." </a>".'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            }    
            if($pagina < $numPaginas){
                echo "<a href='exibir.php?{$query}&p=".($pagina + 1)."' class='controle'>proximo &raquo;</a>".'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            }
        ?>
        <p>
            Fim dos Produtos
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: ,@KaduAmaral, sua solução funciona perfeitamente, mas poderia mostrar quais as outras soluções possiveis?

Comment: Coloquei @RicardoHenrique

Comment: Interessante, envolvi ambos os codigos .php em funções mas desta forma não funcionou.

Comment: Não use funções @RicardoHenrique, deixe o código "livre" rsrs. É porque a segunda parte do código está usando variáveis da primeira parte, se você colocar em funções essas variáveis ficam locais, dentro da função, e uma não pode usar a outra.